# Element of transformation range verses element of column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering if the question "Is $b$ in the range of the linear transformation $x \mapsto Ax$?" is synonymous to asking "Is $b \in ColumnSpace(A)$?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is generally synonymous: The column space of a matrix $A$ is (by definition) the span of its column vectors, i.e. it contains elements of the form $\lambda_{1}c_{1} + ... + \lambda_{n}c_{n}$ where the $c_{i}$ are the columns of the matrix. If $b \in ColumnSpace(A)$ this means b is expressible in this form. But this is exactly the same as $b$ being in the image of your linear transformation. (You can see this by multiplying your matrix $A$ with a general vector).